# How to generate multilevel menu items programmatically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating side menu bar which is generated programatically from json.

I have coded two level items but I hard coded two level ulLi items in html.
But I don't want to hard coded the level of menu items.

I have tried the following code.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu sidebar-nav" ng-repeat="m in modulos">
    <li class="treeview" ng-repeat="(itemIndex, item) in modulos">
        <a ng-click="showSubmenu(itemIndex)">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>{{item.module}}</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="sub-nav" ng-show="isShowing(itemIndex)">
            <li ng-repeat="sub_element in m.submodule">
                <a href="{{sub_element.url}}">{{sub_element.res}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
$scope.modulos = [{
    "module":"Admin System ",
    "adm_modulo_id":1,
    "submodule": [{
        "res":"Angular","url":"#",
        "submodule":[{
            "res":"Angular",
            "url":"#/admin/1"
        },{
            "res":"Linux",
            "url":"#/admin/2"
        },{
            "res":"Server",
            "url":"#/admin/3"
        }]
    },{
        "res":"Linux",
        "url":"#/admin/2"
    },{ 
        "res":"Server",
        "url":"#/admin/3"
    }]

}];
```

Here I have coded two levels of items. But it is a variable. Some items will have 5 levels and another one will have 2 levels.

So based in submodule, I need to write a logic.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with recursion like every other "tree" problem. Recursion in html with angular is done with the template in the html, example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list_node.html">
    ........
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="node in node.children" ng-include="list_node.html"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

On the place where the dots are in my snipper above, you will define what to show (what data on the node item). Example:   `<p>{{node.name}}</p>`

And then in your ng-repeat you just include the template. Example:

```
<ul class="node-indented slide">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.children" ng-include="'list_node.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Adjust this example to your use case and it will work.

Comment: In have tried in following fiddle. but it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/42dx6r5m/

Comment: here is your fiddle edited and working as a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7peswvu/

Comment: Also I would strongly suggest you search and read about the recursion. Browse some examples, it does not have to be JavaScript examples. Once you understand recursion concept, this will be much more clear.

Comment: Either https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree or directive recursion would be better/cleaner alternatives. The later being the best performer probably but requires you to write a directive.